# Post multiple files and data

Tags: php, file, curl

Im trying to upload several files and values at the same time through CURL, but somehow my server's $_FILES keeps getting empty.

My 'text'-data array is:

```
$data = array('value' => 'test', 'application' => 'game');
```

My 'image'-data array is like:

```
$images['16762'] = '@/var/www/tmp/file.jpg';
$images['16423'] = '@/var/www/tmp/file2.jpg';
```

After creating the array's i do a array merge:

```
$postData = array_merge($data, $images);
```

and sent it through curl:

```
$ch = curl_init('post-to-server.url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

On server side Im tring to read the $_FILES but thats empty (as said before). Do I oversee something?